# ARM Assembly : how to output value stored in register

Tags: assembly, arm, logical-operators, calling-convention

I am writing ARM code for a raspberry pi 4 32bit. I need to have the user input two signed int values and then use those values to calculate the operations add, mul, and, orr
and outputted to the screen. When I run the program I get 0 as the result for every operation. The assignment is to display the chosen user input and results of the operations of those inputs.

Attached is the output of the program.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAu9u.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
/* -- two_int_data_op.s -- */



.section .data
/* Prompt message */
prompt: .asciz "Please enter two signed integers: "

/* Response message */
response: .asciz "You entered %d and %d from the keyboard, now some operations on those values!\n"
sum_message: .asciz "Sum of %d and %d is %d\n " /*print out the sum of chosen values*/
product_message: .asciz "Product of %d and %d is %d\n " /*print out the product of chosen values*/
logical_and_message: .asciz "Logical AND of %d and %d is %d \n " /*print out the logical AND of chosen values*/
logical_or_message: .asciz "Logical OR of %d and %d is %d \n " /*print out the logical OR chosen values*/


/* Format pattern for scanf */
pattern: .asciz "%d %d"


/* Where scanf will store the number read */
value_read1: .word 0
value_read2: .word 0

.section .text
.global main
main:
        push {lr}               /* save our return address */

        // use r4, r5 as registers holding pointers to value_read1, and value_read2
        ldr r4, =value_read1
        ldr r5, =value_read2

        ldr r0, =prompt         /* r0 contains pointer to prompt message */
        bl printf               /* call printf to output our prompt */

        ldr r0, =pattern        /* r0 contains pointer to format string for our scan pattern */
        mov r1, r4              /* r1 contains pointer to variable label where our first number is stored */
        mov r2, r5              /* r2 contains pointer to variable label where our second number is stored */
        bl scanf                /* call to scanf */

next:
        ldr r0, =response       /* r0 contains pointer to response message */
        mov r1, r4              /* r4 contains pointer to value_read1 */
        ldr r1, [r1]            /* r1 contains value dereferenced from r1 in previous instruction */
        mov r2, r5
        ldr r2, [r2]
        bl printf               /* call printf to output our response */

        mov r1, r4              /* r4 contains pointer to value_read1 */
        ldr r1, [r1]            /* r1 contains value dereferenced from r1 in previous instruction */
        mov r2, r5
        ldr r2, [r2]
        add r6, r1, r2          /* calculate the sum of the two integers, store result r6 */
        ldr r0, =sum_message    /* r0 contains pointer to sum  message */
        bl printf               /* call printf to output our response */

        mov r1, r4              /* r4 contains pointer to value_read1*/
        ldr r1, [r1]            /* r1 contains value dereferenced from r1 in previous instruction */
        mov r2, r5
        ldr r2, [r2]
        mul r6, r1, r2          /* calculate the product of  the two integers, store result r6 */
        ldr r0, =product_message /* r0 contains pointer to product message*/
        bl printf                       /* call printf to output our response */

        mov r1, r4                      /* r4 contains pointer to value_read1*/
        ldr r1, [r1]                    /* r1 contains value dereferenced from r1 in previous instruction */
        mov r2, r5
        ldr r2, [r2]
        and r6, r1, r2                  /* bitwise and r1 and r2, store result in r6*/
        ldr r0, =logical_and_message    /* r0 contains pointer to logical and mesage*/
        bl printf

        mov r1, r4                      /* r4 cntains pointer value_read1 */
        ldr r1, [r1]                    /* r1 contains value dereferenced from r1 in previous instruction */
        mov r2, r5
        ldr r2, [r2]
        orr r6, r1, r2                  /* bitwise or r1, r2, sotre result in r6 */
        ldr r0, =logical_or_message     /* ro contains pointer to logical or message */
        bl printf

        mov r0, #0              /* exit code 0 = program terminated normally */
        pop {pc}                /* exit our main function */
```

I was expecting r6 to output the calculated value of the operation. Instead all 4 operations are resulting in 0.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  For future reference, you can format code blocks with `\`\`\`` on its own line at the beginning and end.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for more info on formatting.  Also, for your program's output, please copy/paste it as text, instead of using a screenshot.  [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping your code in a debugger?  This should help you determine exactly where it misbehaves.  When you do, please edit your post with more details about what you found, which will help narrow down your question and make it easier to answer.

Comment: The fourth argument passed to a function goes in `r3`, not `r6`.  I'm not sure where you would have got the idea that it's `r6`.  (If there are more than four then they get passed on the stack; `r6` is never used for argument/parameter passing.)  See https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/main/aapcs32/aapcs32.rst#machine-registers for the authoritative description of the calling convention.  Another note from there is that you have to preserve the contents of r4-r11, so you need to add r4 and r5 to your push/pop at the top and bottom of your function.